# Is there a better solution than Option for handling "cannot borrow as mutable more than once at a time"?

Tags: rust

I have the structs `Foo` and `Bar`. `Foo` contains an array of `Bar` and a private method to operate on `Bar`:

```
pub struct Bar;

pub struct Foo {
    bars: [Bar; 10],
}

impl Foo {
    pub fn process_all(&mut self) {
        for bar in self.bars.iter_mut() {
            self.process_single(bar);
        }
    }

    fn process_single(&mut self, bar: &mut Bar) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This won't work because both `self` and one of its contained bars can't be borrowed at the same time.

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
```

One way of solving this in my case is an `Option`. I then have the ability to take ownership of the array in the function and then later giving it back to the struct after the process is done:

```rust
pub struct Bar;

pub struct Foo {
    bars: Option<[Bar; 10]>,
}

impl Foo {
    pub fn process_all(&mut self) {
        let bars = self.bars.take().unwrap();

        for bar in bars {
            self.process_single(bar);
        }

        self.bars = Some(bars);
    }

    fn process_single(&mut self, bar: &mut Bar) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This feels very hacky; is there a better way?

Comment: Niko wrote a [nice blog post](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2018/11/01/after-nll-interprocedural-conflicts/) about this and similar cases.

Comment: Do you have reasons to use `self` (or any mutable part other than the bar) in `process_single`  ? If not you can just [make it a free function](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3a313f2ca758bdf422e6adebf67689c2).

Comment: @SvenMarnach That is indeed a good post with the same problem.

Comment: @DenysSéguret I do, because in reality my Foo has more data that is touched. I guess I went a bit too much in an OOP solution...

Comment: TL;DR the duplicate: make more structs. Move `process_single` to a struct that contains what it needs to work, does not contain any `Bar`, and pass the `Bar` to it. Then your `Foo` holds the `Bar` array and the new type.